# Azure "Web apps" service: auto-install npm modules from package.json

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-web-app-service, package.json

I deployed a node.js app in an azure "web apps" container. I added the "node_modules" folder to .gitignore and let azure install modules from package.json.

However, most modules do not get automatically installed and i have to open the instance's command line and install them manually using "npm install".

I am using node v0.12.0 and here is my package.json:

```
{
 "main": "server.js",
 "scripts": {
   "start": "node server.js"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
  "body-parser": "^1.12.4",
  "cors": "^2.6.1",
  "express": "*",
  "gulp": "^3.8.11",
  "gulp-jshint": "^1.11.0",
  "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.3",
  "moment": "^2.10.3",
  "mongoose": "^4.0.3"
},
"engines": {
  "node": "0.12.0"
}
}
```

How can I enable automatic installation of modules through azure web apps and not be obliged to push the "node_modules" folder with each commit?

Comment: This may be related to either devDependencies that should be renamed to dependencies or native node modules that are failing to be built (mongoose) since Azure does not support native node.js modules. Can you paste the install log of Azure?

Comment: @Jonathan Muller thx, I am new to azure you mean the deployement log?

Comment: yup, so we can see wich package broke the build

Comment: @JonathanMuller that's the thing it is deploying successfully, I didn't know what the issue was until I opened the instance command line.

Comment: it is not necessary to commit node_modules! Like @Jonathan Muller said: use `dependencies` instead of `devDependencies`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Azure does not install the `devDependencies`.
If you need them on production, it is not `devDependencies` but `dependencies`

In your `package.json`, `devDependencies` should be renamed to `dependencies`

This kind of thing appens when you `npm install --save-dev`.

Production dependency (needed to run): `npm install --save`
Otherwise (build tools, jshint, etc.): `npm install --save-dev`